# Motional EMF inside material with resistance

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

A square loop is cut out of a thick sheet of material with each side of resistance R. It is then placed
so that the top portion is in a uniform magnetic field B, and is allowed to fall under
gravity.

[image]

Griffiths in his solution writes : $$\varepsilon = 4IR$$

But gives no justification for that equation.

I agree (from previous proofs on his textbook) that $ V= IR$ on every portion of the square **except** the top portion.

The proof that $ V= IR$ assumes the only driving force of the charges is the electric field (which is not true in the case of the top portion of the square).

Moreover, the proof that emf equals the potential difference is valid only under the assumption that the emf generated on material with zero or negligible resistance.

Can someone derive rigorously why $\varepsilon = 4IR$ ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: He appears to be assuming that each side of the loop has a resistance of R.

Comment: @R.W.Bird reread my question because you did not understand it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try again.  The question says: "A square loop, (cut out of a thick sheet of material), with each side of resistance R", is dropped from within a uniform magnetic field. Then the changing flux, (or the motion of the top through the field) generates an electromotive force, ε, which causes a current flow: ε = I(4R).  In this case, the loop is accelerating from the field, so the, ε, will increase as a function of time. As the current increases it will interact with the field, producing a force which opposes the rate of fall. Though the, ε, is generated in the top of the loop,the current flow through that section still causes a voltage drop do to the resistance in that section. The voltage drop on each of the other sections will be (1/4)ε.

Comment: Nice story, does not answer the question..

Comment: try reading again these lines : 

"The proof that V=IR assumes the only driving force of the charges is the electric field (which is not true in the case of the top portion of the square).

Moreover, the proof that emf equals the potential difference is valid only under the assumption that the emf generated on material with zero or negligible resistance."

Comment: Note that if a circular loop were completely within a changing magnetic field, the emf within each little segment would be matched by the IR drop.  There would be no voltage difference between any two points in the loop.